# Setting limits to resource usage with Supervisord

Tags: celery, supervisord

I'm using Supervisor to control a Celery worker that takes an album containing one or more photos and generates a video from them using `avconv`. Unfortunately, for bigger albums the process is using too many resources and being shut down.

Is there a parameter I can set in the Supervisor config file I can set to renice the process in order to limit the resources it uses and prevent it being killed off? I haven't been able to find any in the documentation, but this seems like an obvious need. Alternatively, does Celery allow something similar so I can set it there?

Comment: What resources specifically are you talking about? How exactly is the process being shut down and by what? nice only affects priority, if your process is being killed by the kernel then it is probably excess memory usage at fault - `nice` will not help with this.

Comment: The messages in the syslog are "Out of memory: Kill process 12714 (python) score 651 or sacrifice child" and "Killed process 12714 (python) total-vm:1051652kB, anon-rss:743220kB, file-rss:72kB'. So it sounds like you're right and excess memory usage is the issue.

Comment: this is more an `avconv` issue than a celery issue. I'm not too familiar with what you are trying to do, but I'd imagine that there is a way to convert arbitrary numbers of images into a video without exhausting memory - I'd suggest searching for this and maybe opening a question in SuperUser if you can't find an answer

Answer (score 1):

[Superlance](https://superlance.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) plugin can be used to limit memory usage of any supervisord managed process.
Supervisord can natively manage process priority, set it's umask, etc.. See [docs](http://supervisord.org/configuration.html#program-x-section-settings) for details.